# Imgur image validation using preg_match

Tags: php, validation, url, preg-match, imgur

I'd like to use the preg_match function (procedural, not oop) to validate user provided urls for images hosted on imgur.com

The purpose is to include the called image into a php page (hotlink) where users can use the image as their avatar/profile image.

As far as I know, a valid imgur hotlink is:

```
https://i.imgur.com/FILENAME.XYZ
```

Where "FILENAME" is something like "2lcqfvJ" and "XYZ" is the image format like "jpg". Example:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UXVL.jpg
```

I've some difficulties to figure out the pattern for the validation. I use this method yet to identify valid tinypic and imageshack valid urls

I tried this to check the url provided by the user, but it seems to not work:

```
if ( !preg_match('/^(http|https):\/\/(.*?)\.(imgur)\.(com)\/.(png|jpg|gif|PNG|JPG|GIF)$/i',$url) )
```

Passing the url above (https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UXVL.jpg) the function doesn't recognize it as a valid imgur link. So I can imagine I've done something wrong with the regular expression.

Comment: !preg_match('/^(http|https):\/\/(.*?)\.(imgur)\.(com)\/(.*?)\.(png|jpg|gif|PNG|JPG|GIF)$/i',$url)

Answer (score 1):

*(Posted answer on behalf of the question author)*.

The pattern below works:

```
!preg_match('/^(http|https):\/\/(.*?)\.(imgur)\.(com)\/(.*?)\.(png|jpg|gif|PNG|JPG|GIF)$/i',$url)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex can be simplified:

```
!preg_match('~^https?://i\.imgur\.com/\w+\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$~i', $url)
```